# How to code to force run an indicator when crossing a manual horizontal line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trendline

I have an indicator that works fine to send a webhook message on different conditions like 3 green high cross, 20 EMA cross etc and trades go well... however sometimes I find random opportunities on chart upon crossing down/up a horizontal/trend line, where I wanted to invoked this indicator to run... is there a way to achieve this. This line is managed/moved by me on case to case basis to different prices on chart as shown in below image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HATW2.png

I tried a fixed /static massage that works fine to send a message up on crossing line, however my need is a custom indicator in which some function, custom logic are there, hence seeking help on how to catch a trendline cross through an indicator

Comment: Please share your code in an edit to the question. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User drawings are not accessible by pinescript.

If all you need is a horizontal line, you can have an `input.float()` and define the price there.

If you need more complicated lines (e.g. trend lines, conditional lines etc.), you need to create your lines with `line.new()` and then access its price with `line.get_y2()` or `line.get_price()` and set your alerts based on the return value.